# Función flecha vs función regular

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Siguiendo un tutorial de **Vue**, en el que se hace un `fetch` a una **API** que regresa una imagen de gatos, llegué de pronto a una situación curiosa.

```javascript
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {   
    catSrc: null,
  },

...

this.catSrc = null;
let res = fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search",{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": API_KEY,
      "Accept":"application/json",
      },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      return data[0].url;
   });
      
 let getImg = () => {
   res.then((result) => {
   this.catSrc = result;
   });
 };

getImg();
```

Lo anterior hace el `fetch` y logro devolver el valor de la promesa a la variable dinamica de **Vue**, pero como primero se me ocurrió "convertir" la función flecha, la alternativa nunca me regresó el valor que sí regresa la función flecha.

¿Alguien puede explicarme por qué de esto?

La función "normal" que traté de utilizar fue:

```javascript
let getImg = function () {
  res.then(function (result) {
    this.catSrc = result;
  });
};

getImg();
```

Comment: Básicamente a que el ámbito al que se refiere `this` cuando usas la función tradicional, es el de esa función. Y en las funciones flecha `this` proviene del contexto léxico circundante, o sea el ámbito en que se crean. Te sugiero leer https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparaci%C3%B3n_de_funciones_tradicionales_con_funciones_flecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es por cómo cambia el contexto de *this* en una función normal y en una función flecha. El contexto de ejecución cambia mucho.

La propiedad this.catSrc pertenece al contexto del objeto vue, cuando se declaran nuevas funciones con function() que no son propiedades de un objeto estas funciones tienen su propio contexto. Por lo que dentro de ellas this ya no pertenece al objeto vue si no que pertenece al contexto de la function() que puede ser el objeto window por defecto o undefined en el modo estricto de js.

Las funciones flecha no declaran nuevos contextos y por tanto cualquier this dentro de ellas hace referencia al contexto padre, en este caso el objeto vue que es el que tiene la propiedad que interesa.

Comment: Como podria hacer la llamada al this del entorno de Vue dentro de la funcional regular?

Comment: Dentro de un objeto Vue puedes declarar dentro de la propiedad methods nuevas funciones que pueden ser llamadas manteniendo el contexto this al ser propiedades de un objeto (https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html). Sin embargo, la función del then no veo forma que pueda funcionar sin función flecha.

Comment: gracias por contestar